# Error during setup of Concerto adaptive testing platform in WAMP environment

Tags: php, mysql, r, xampp, wamp

I need to setup  Concerto platform in WAMP environment to develop adaptive tests. The link to the Concerto platform is here http://code.google.com/p/concerto-platform

This is what I have done on my side:
1)Setup WAMP web server 
2) Setup R language 
3) Setup localhost and checked the working of php, mysql and R.

Now I have run into problems during the setup of Concerto,
specifically after the penultimate step 6 of this installation guide 
../concerto-platform/wiki/installation3

The Concerto setup successfully performs the php and mysql database creation.
Hereafter, the Concerto setup fails to recognize the R version while running the setup script as recommended in installation of the download ../concerto-platform/downloads/list (zip file 3.8 MB)

I have extracted the contents of the Concerto source installation zip file to  'C:/wampp/htdocs/concerto' directory and the setup script index.php resides in the 'C:/wampp/htdocs/concerto/setup/' sub-directory.

When I run the setup script from the browser (localhost/concerto/setup/index.php) I get the following error. 
"NOTICE: undefined offset 0 in C:\wampp\htdocs\concerto\setup\index.php on line 97.
R version installation must be atleast R >= v2.12. Your R version is :v       "

It is unable to get and display the R version installed which is in fact R v2.14
When I checked line97 and the php functions referenced, I noticed the following code snippet.

```
public static function rscript_check()
{
    $array = array();
    $return = 0;
    exec("'" . Ini::$path_r_script . "' -e 1+1", $array, $return);
    return ($return == 0);
}

public static function r_version_check($version)
{
    $elems = explode(".", $version);
    if($elems[0]>2) return true;
    if($elems[0]==2)
    {
        if($elems[1]>=12) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static function get_r_version()
{
    $output = array();
    $return = 0;
    exec("'" . Ini::$path_r_script . "' --version -e 1+1", $output, $return);
    $version = substr($output[0],10);
    $version = substr($version,0,  strpos($version, " "));
    echo $version;
    return $version;
}
```

My hunch is that somehow the exec function is not working perfectly, since I performed the equivalent cmdline invoking in start > run "Cmd /c G:/R/R-2.14.0/bin/Rscript.exe" --version -e 1+1" and was able to get the result checking manually but not via the setup functions described above. I enquired with the Concerto admins and a new discussion forum has  been inaugurated only recently http://www.psychometrics.cam.ac.uk/page/343/discussion-forum.htm

Hence, I turned in here for help from the SO community.
Any pointers for setting up this installation is greatly appreciated.
PS: Here are the settings I entered in the settings.php file provided in the zip file

```
 >{phpstart

 >    //MySQL
->$db_host = "localhost";
->$db_port = "3306";
->$db_user = "root";
->$db_password = "";
->$db_name = "test";

 >//paths
->$path_external = "http://localhost/concerto"; //e.g. http://domain.com/concerto/
->$path_r_script = "G:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.0/bin/Rscript.exe"; //e.g. /usr/bin/Rscript
->$path_r_exe = "G:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.0/bin/R.exe"; //e.g. /usr/bin/R
->$path_php_exe = "C:/wampp/php"; //e.g. /usr/bin/php
->$path_mysql_home = "C:/wampp/mysql/bin"; //Home directory of MySQL server. It will be probably needed if you want to install Concerto on Windows platform. e.g. C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5
->$path_sock = "C:/wampp/htdocs/concerto/socks/"; //leave blank for default - /[concerto_installation_path]/socks/
->$path_temp = "C:/wampp/htdocs/concerto/temp/"; //leave blank for default - /[concerto_installation_path]/temp/

 >//R connection
->$r_instances_persistant = true; //true  - R instances are persistant and open throughout the whole test ( faster, but consumes more system resources, EXPERIMENTAL ), false - R instances are closed and restored when needed ( slower, but consumes less system resources )                           
->$r_instances_persistant_instance_timeout = 300; //after set period of instance inactivity in seconds the instance will be closed
->$r_instances_persistant_server_timeout = 420; //after set period of server inactivity in seconds the server will be closed ( new instances can restart it anytime )
->$r_max_execution_time = 120; //maximum R execution time ( prevents infinite loops in R on server )

 >//general
->$timezone = 'Europe/London';
 ->$public_registration = false;
 ->$public_registration_default_UserType_id = 4;

  >//remote client
  ->$remote_client_password = "pass";

  ->//ALWAYS RUN /setup AFTER CHANGING SETTINGS IN THIS FILE!
 ->?}phpend
```

I will appreciate for any of your thoughts and ideas from your personal experience or from running a quick concerto install in your WAMP/LAMP environments. I am running this on Win XP myself. Maybe someone can suggest some workarounds (around exec() if exec is indeed the culprit) on this topic.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same configuration and it worked fine for me.
At first, I'll suggest you to use R2.12 instead of R2.14 you can get it here http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.12.1/

I'll also suggest you to change your SETTINGS.php file by changing the "R connection" section.
Add the following lines

```
//R connection
$server_socks_type = "TCP"; // UNIX or TCP, choose TCP for any other OS than Linux
$server_host = "127.0.0.1"; //is socket server set to TCP, choose host to connect to
$server_port = "80"; //if socket server set to TCP, choose port used for connection
$r_instances_persistant_instance_timeout = 300; //after set period of instance inactivity in seconds the instance will be closed
$r_instances_persistant_server_timeout = 420; //after set period of server inactivity in seconds the server will be closed ( new instances can restart it anytime )
$r_max_execution_time = 30; //maximum R execution time ( prevents infinite loops in R on server )
$unix_locale = ""; //Unix locale LANG variable. Must be installed on the system. Leave blank for none/default.
```

As you're using WAMP you have to make some changes.

Hope it'll help you.

**Ghost**